# Standard Error and Coefficient Calculation

Tags: regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error

I'm trying to calculate the missing coefficient and standard error from the question posted below. The question does not provide any information beyond the excel output of a 3 variable regression on Excel. I understand that the standard error for variable "HML" (from the picture below) is calculated as coefficient * t-stat. But how should I calculate both the coefficient and standard error for variable "SMB"?[image]

Comment: Hint: use the "Lower 95%" and "Upper 95%" columns to find the coefficient.

Comment: But standard error is an input necessary for the calculation of 95% confidence interval right?

Comment: These confidence intervals are *symmetric:* that means the parameter estimates lie exactly halfway between the endpoints.

Comment: So, is it right to say that the coefficient is equal to average of the lower and upper interval (0.883171809)?

Comment: See for yourself: look at the other rows in the table.